# Slow Bot Framework performance resulting in conversation issues

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, chatbot

I am experiencing an issue with a chat bot I have developed using the Microsoft Bot Framework. While testing it on both my local machine and while deployed to a VPS running Windows Server, there is a fairly noticable delay between posting a message to the chat bot, receiving a response from the chat bot, and the posted message showing in the log.

[image: This can be seen here.]

This seems to result in another issue where posting messages to the chat bot in quick succession can result in the bot's state not updating properly, and it remains stuck on the previous dialog.

[image: This can be seen here.]

I have just performed a test using Skype instead of the emulator included with the Bot Framework, and the same issue occurs there too.

[image: This can be seen here.]

Are there any ways these above issues can be resolved or mitigated, and if so, what are they?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Can you tell me what requires rephrasing please? I thought I had been quite clear in both demonstrating the issues I am experiencing (that the chat bot I have developed does not respond to messages in a timely fashion, and that this appears to result in faults with the conversation flow) and what my end goal is (either resolve the issue with the delay in the responses, or if the delay is unavoidable, at least maintain the proper conversation flow).

Comment: Sorry, I made the assumption that SO users would be able to infer that I would like a response that at least pointed me in the direction of a resolution to my issues. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Which log are you referring to?

There are no Thread.Sleep() calls in my code - both the framework and the bot I have built around it are designed to operate asynchronously. There are also no calls to any similar methods such as Task.Delay().

I have tested my code in both release and debug mode, altering this does not make any difference.

As stated at the beginning of my question, the issue occurs when testing the bot on my local development machine and also when testing the same bot hosted on the VPS. Therefore the issue is independent of connection speed and routing.

Comment: The log I am referring to is in the bottom-right corner of the animations I posted alongside my question, underneath the title "Log". It is a feature of the bot framework emulator which records the requests made to and the responses received from the bot.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by how fast the emulator is - it is used to provide a basic interface to the chat bot for testing purposes before it is deployed to a service like Skype. I've just performed a similar test using Skype instead of the emulator, and the issue occurs there too.